# Неправильное количество позиционных аргументов

Tags: python, dxf

Написал код на питоне, который должен в dxf файле создавать прямоугольник по заданным координатам, но вкидывается ошибка

> TypeError: LinkedEntities.**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import ezdxf
from ezdxf.entities import Polyline

class DXFGenerator(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("DXF Generator")
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        width_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Width:")
        self.width_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        height_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Height:")
        self.height_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        generate_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Generate DXF")
        generate_button.clicked.connect(self.generate_dxf)

        self.layout.addWidget(width_label, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.width_input, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(height_label, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.height_input, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(generate_button, 2, 0, 1, 2)

        self.open_file_dialog_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Open file dialog")
        self.open_file_dialog_button.clicked.connect(self.open_file_dialog)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.open_file_dialog_button, 3, 0, 1, 2)

        self.filename = ""

    def generate_dxf(self):
        width = float(self.width_input.text())
        height = float(self.height_input.text())

        doc = ezdxf.new("R2010")
        modelspace = doc.modelspace()

        block = doc.blocks.new("Rectangle")
        layout = block

        points = [(0, 0), (width, 0), (width, height), (0, height)]

        pline = Polyline(points)
        layout.add_entity(pline)

        doc.saveas(self.filename)
        print("DXF file generated.")

    def open_file_dialog(self):
        file_dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self)
        file_dialog.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ExistingFile)

        if file_dialog.exec_():
            self.filename = file_dialog.selectedFiles()[0]
            print("File selected:", self.filename)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = DXFGenerator()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: И покажите полный стек-трейс ошибки, сейчас совершенно непонятно, к какой строке вашего кода эта ошибка относится.